# How Can I Get Back The Old C++ Empty Project Items In Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

There used to be "references, external dependencies, header files, resource files and source files" items in an empty c++ project that I created in Visual Studio. however, I don't know why after I reset my pc and install Visual Studio Community again, I got these weird items when I create an empty c++ project from Visual Studio.

Sorry about the language tho its the same on any other language I just want the old visual studio empty project items back.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot (Empty C++ Project)]

Answer (score 0):

You've created a universal Windows app not a plain c++ application. If the option to create normal c++ applications is missing there's a chance you didn't select the appropriate options when installing visual studio.

Comment: Well, I Just Relaunched The Installer And Add Some Features To My Visual Studio, And Updated It. Thanks You Very Much It Worked + I Also Changed The Language. 
Have A Nice Day